# How to pick columns in ASCII input file in a loop

Tags: java, file, loops, inputstream, filereader

I have an ASCII file with about 160 lines (let's say `result.txt`), which has the following content:

```
Just a comment
with two or more lines

File title, Versionnumber

Time    Value1     Value2     Value3    Value4
(s)     (m)        (m/s)      (km)      (N)
0.002   8.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00 10.000E+01
0.040   9.850E+00  1.221E-04  0.000E+00 12.000E+01
0.060   12.780E+00 1.312E-02  0.000E+00 16.000E+05
...
```

I now want to work with each value-column based on the time column. The idea is to declare a map and put the value for each time step inside it. So the first map for the `Value1` would look like this:

```
0.002 -> 8.000E+00
0.040 -> 9.850E+00
0.060 -> 12.780E+00
```

The map for the `Value2`, `Value3`, ..., `ValueN` would look similar to the assignment shown above. The time step could be a `double` whereas the value could be a `String` (I know how to convert them for my needs).

What is the easiest, fastest and most efficient way to do this?

**UPDATE:** This is how I read the file:

```
FileInputStream fis;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // split columns
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

What is the best way to split columns?

Comment: Why is `0.002` pointing to the `Value2` (or `Value3` ?) column, but the other two are pointing to the `Value1` column?

Comment: Read the file line by line, split, call put on N maps in a loop. - Not exactly rocket science, so of what are you afraid?

Comment: @TIMBiegeleisen Sorry, mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: Follow the advice given by @laune ... this is a straightforward problem.  If you show us what you have attempted so far we can give more advice.  SO is not a cut and paste free coding service.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Edited my post and added some code.

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive.  Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code you can use to fill in the skeleton you already have:

```
// class level declaration
Map<Double, String> timeSeriesMap = new HashMap<Double, String>();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // split current line on any amount of whitespace
    String[] parts = line.trim().split("\\s+");
    Double key     = Double.valueOf(parts[0]);
    String value   = parts[1];

    // add the (key, value) pair to your Map
    timeSeriesMap.put(key, value);

    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Squeeze a `trim()` into `line.split()` to avoid unpleasant surprises from leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem (thanks to Tim Biegeleisen). If someone faces the same problem, here is the code:

```
public void myMethod() {
    // TreeMap will sort the Map by key
    TreeMap<Double, String> map = new TreeMap<Double, String>();

    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split("\t");
            if (parts.length >= 2 && isNumeric(parts[0])) {
                // remove whitespaces
                map.put(Double.parseDouble(parts[0].replaceAll(" ", "")), parts[1].replaceAll(" ", ""));
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}

boolean isNumeric(String string) {
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Then all you have to do is:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fis);
while(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
    double value1 = sc.nextDouble();
    double value2 = sc.nextDouble();
    double value3 = sc.nextDouble();
    double value4 = sc.nextDouble();
    double value5 = sc.nextDouble();
    double value6 = sc.nextDouble();

    // do what you need to do
}
```

Oracle has a tutorial on how to use the scanner which might be useful:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html